# Paging with WCF data service

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, pagination, wcf-data-services

My question is about how you handle paging with a WCF data service. The way I want to use it, is execute a query (passing page size and current page), and get back the results of that query and also the paging information like total number of pages, current page number and page size. This paging information is used by the client (which is another service that transforms the result to JSON for a mobile application that consumes it) to handle next/previous buttons.

However, using LINQ on a WCF data service is too limited, it doesn't support the LINQ expression I need.

I tried creating a service operation in the WCF **data** service, but I can only return IQueryable collections of data entities, so I cannot return a custom entity that also contains paging information.

Is there a way to do implement paging for a WCF data service so that I next to the result I also get back paging information?

EDIT: because of the limitations of WCF data services, I switched to a normal WCF service. To be honest, I don't see why anyone would ever want to use a data service with these severe limitations!

Comment: Sorry, I missed the **data** part of your question. WCF **Data** Services are horribly limiting. It's a RESTful service so you can just pass page and page size information in the URL. If you're using it so that you can write LINQ queries against it - good luck. WCF Data Services is an implementation of OData which puts restrictions on how a query can be formatted. You're far better off writing a WCF service where you actually have control over the method calls.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer :-/ Ok, thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that WCF data services is way too limited, and the solution for me was to switch to a regular WCF service so that I could use full LINQ and define data contracts myself.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Paging Provider for WCF Data Services [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960143.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg191846)

Comment: That doesn't help me I think. It only has a next-page mechanism, but the client doesn't know about total number of pages...

Comment: True. Not sure but then I think your only option is to have a bespoke DataModel that contains both the data and the paging details (page count, current page, size etc..). Although to achieve this you probably need to create a custom Typed Data Service Provider (see first article).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Skip` and `Take` to perform client side paging of data from the WCF data service, such as:

```
var items = (from i in ctx.MyEntities
             select i).Skip(StartIndex).Take(PageSize)
```

Where *StartIndex* is the beginning position of the data you want returned and *PageSize* is the number of elements max to return.