# WCF paging for posible large payloads

Tags: c#, wcf, paging

Currently our WCF services all handle some type of paging when the operation returns a collection of objects. However we found that some operations can, in some scenarios, return a collection of not so trivial objects which end up producing responses that surpass the 64K threshold that all best practices documentation beg us to try to maintain to optimize the underlying tcp channel everything works on.

For example, our service can return a list of movies being shown in a theatre and the client can ask daily pricing, showtimes and sit availability for each movie for some time period; that is "give me the list of movies being shown and daily information for the next 30 days".
The problem is that we can't simply restrain the number of days the client can ask for.. so even if we restrict the number of movies returned in a single call, a client requesting info for 30+ days will produce a large response that we to avoid as much as possible.

A streaming binding is not possible since all our services are 1 way with some type of queue as a channel.
What kind of contract design can we look into to manage the size of these types of results? Of course we also want to avoid over complex contracts that have the ability to page every aspect of the response since that benefits no one.

Comment: I wonder if you have a `design problem`. Why return the daily information for next 30 days for the movies in the same request?  Would it not be better to get the list of movies and then only when the user selects something, fetch the daily information.  That way you are not fetching data that may not be used by the user

Comment: @User52784246, the client has the ability to include or exclude the daily information from the response but some of our applications need to include it to reduce the number of trips to the server in a single UI action. For those apps, it is a technical necessity.

Comment: Reducing the `number of trips` is a good strategy for **small** amounts of data, but for large data responses such as in your case the _overhead of multiple trips_ vs the _time_ to receive a single large response, the former would be pretty insignificant

Answer (score 1):

Beyond a certain point, you must make a choice. You can't both send a heavy bunch of data and stay below 64k...

There are probably other options and approaches but here are some examples :

- Adding paging options in the request itself and explain to the user that he must use it.
- Force paging in the answer if needed (even if not required in the question by the user) and specify it to the user (number of items returned / number of remaining items). 
  To make it easier to use you can make a kind of stateful service with a specific-token present in answer which give to user the abililty to ask directly the next resultset. This way, he doesn't have to handle explicitly the page size/skip, he gets something more fluid by just asking "now send me the next resultset which correspond to this token".
- Find a way to simplify contract : removing useless fields, express things concisely...
- Binary compress data if not
- Changing the binding (you look like to have already thought about it)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Richard. I can find known APIs using the token paging but I'd appreciate implementation references or anything discussing the pattern.

Comment: Hint : search for "continuation token", "skip token" or "server driven paging". Here is a Microsoft sample, it's for OData but it can drive you in the way to implement it : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/02/02/server-paging-in-data-services.aspx . Maybe there are also more "finite" sources available to implement it in soap bindings.

Comment: You could also have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503562/paging-with-wcf-data-service

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of contract design can we look into to manage the size of these types of results?

Instead of requesting a number of days (*for the next 30 days*) it's more appropriate to request a concrete period (*between "Oct 4 '14" and "Oct 14 '14"*) and validate if length of this concrete period is shorter than some limit (for example, *30 days*). Period length limit is selected based on *64k transfer threshold* or some other technical factor.

There is usually no problem to break long period into smaller periods (if necessary), do 2-3 requests from client application and concatenate results.